# How do I download an image from a URL and save it to my computer?

Tags: objective-c, image, macos, download

How would I download an image from a URL, and have that saved to the computer using Objective-C? This is what I got so far:

```
NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

UIImage *imageFromURL = [self getImageFromURL:@"https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png"];

[self saveImage:imageFromURL withFileName:@"Google Logo" ofType:@"png" inDirectory:documentsDirectoryPath];

UIImage *imageFromWeb = [self loadImage:@"Google Logo" ofType:@"png" inDirectory:documentsDirectoryPath];
```

Xcode complains about UIIMage, trying to replace with NSImage. It also complains about an undeclared identifier 'self'.

I need to make an HTTP call to perform this as well. Explain this to me like I'm 5.

Comment: so it is a Mac OS X program?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to save to the hard drive of a Mac OS X computer.

Comment: Is this to be done using an iOS app (you tagged the question with iOS) or is this to be done with a Mac app?

Comment: I didn't do that, somebody else did. I want to do this on the Mac. It's not even an app, I'm using the Mac Command Terminal application.

Comment: If this isn't an iOS app, then why does your posted code use iOS specific APIs such as `UIImage`?

Comment: @rmaddy, no idea, I'm a complete newb at this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the code to Save the image into document Directory.

```
-(void)saveImagesInLocalDirectory
{
        NSString * documentsDirectoryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *imgName = @"image.png";
            NSString *imgURL = @"www.example.com/image/image.png";
            NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
            NSString *writablePath = [documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:imgName];

            if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writablePath]){
                // file doesn't exist
                NSLog(@"file doesn't exist");
                if (imgName) {
                    //save Image From URL
                    [self getImageFromURLAndSaveItToLocalData:imgName fileURL:imgURL inDirectory:documentsDirectoryPath];
                }
            }
            else{
                // file exist
                NSLog(@"file exist");
            }
}

-(void) getImageFromURLAndSaveItToLocalData:(NSString *)imageName fileURL:(NSString *)fileURL inDirectory:(NSString *)directoryPath {
    NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fileURL]];

    NSError *error = nil;
    [data writeToFile:[directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", imageName]] options:NSAtomicWrite error:&error];

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error Writing File : %@",error);
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Image %@ Saved SuccessFully",imageName);
    }
}
```

And this is the one method code..

```
-(void)saveImagesInLocalDirectory
{
        NSString * documentsDirectoryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *imgName = @"image.png";
            NSString *imgURL = @"www.example.com/image/image.png";
            NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
            NSString *writablePath = [documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:imgName];

            if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writablePath]){
                // file doesn't exist
                NSLog(@"file doesn't exist");
                    //save Image From URL
                    NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: imgURL]];

                    NSError *error = nil;
                    [data writeToFile:[documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", imgName]] options:NSAtomicWrite error:&error];

                   if (error) {
                          NSLog(@"Error Writing File : %@",error);
                   }else{
                          NSLog(@"Image %@ Saved SuccessFully",imgName);
                   }
            }
            else{
                // file exist
                NSLog(@"file exist");
            }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, but I'm a complete newb. Is there a way to do it without using custom methods? If not, it's not a big deal, I'll still accept the answer after I figure out how it works.

Comment: The method is not a big deal i have just created it for abstraction bcoz in my app i am using this same method multiple time thats all. You can add the second method code in first method thats okay.

Comment: Okay, let me give it a spin, once I get it going, I'll come back and accept your answer.

Comment: Check out my update i have created one method code. tell me if you get any error.

Comment: You have to excuse me, I'm a complete newb to Objective-C, so I'm deathly afraid of attempting methods until I have learned how to implement them properly. I am beginning to attempt it now. Thanks for following up, I'm going to give it a try and let you know as soon as I get it.

Comment: I just used your single method answer, works superbly! You are a genius!

Comment: sorry I wasn't able to upvote you before, I didn't have the required rep. I just upvoted you now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution!

```
+(BOOL)downloadMedia :(NSString*)url_ :(NSString*)name{
    NSString *stringURL = url_;
    NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
    NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    if ( urlData )
    {
        NSArray       *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,name];
        [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

+(UIImage*)loadMedia :(NSString*)name{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *getImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:name];
    UIImage *img_ = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:getImagePath];
    return img_;
}
```